# На изображение наложен тест через position absolute, так же действует hover на это изображение,но прерывается как только навестись на текст в absolute

Tags: html, css, hover, absolute

есть карточка, она является бекграундом, на нее через position:absolute наложен текст, так же карточке задан hover эффект, но как только наводишь на текст наложенный через absolute, эффект hover пропадает, то есть по сути внутри карточки появляется слепое пятно, как сделать что бы hover игнорировал наложенный через position absolute текст
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

pointer-events: none; кому то надо подучить свойства)

Comment: Старайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.